# WPF unhandled exception handler and preserve call stack

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception

I have a WPF application and I need to write a mini dump file whenever my application encounters an unhandled exception for help with debugging. However, every time the exception handler is called, the stack is completely unwound to the handler and there is no useful state that I can use in the dump file.

I I tried to subscribe to both of these and the stack is unwound for both of them:

```
Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
```

I tried the same with a console app and the stack is not unwound so it is definitely WPF-related. The exception and handlers both happen in the main thread.

Here are 2 code samples that you can see this easily. Just set breakpoints in each handler and observe the call stack when the breakpoints are hit.

Console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
        int foo = 5;
        ++foo;
        throw new ApplicationException("blah");
        ++foo;
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("blah");
    }
}
```

WPF app:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Current_DispatcherUnhandledException);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
        int foo = 5;
        ++foo;
        throw new ApplicationException("blah");
        ++foo;
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

    void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {}

    void Current_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried out CurrentDomain_UnhandeledException in WPF (.NET 4.5) and it is working just fine. Although I set it up in Window_Loaded and caused the crash in a button click. And I know it works fine in .NET 4.0 as well. Which .NET version are you using? Can you try my scenario, instead of App.OnStartup (perhaps WPF isn't fully initialized yet)? Otherwise post the two exception's (Console vs WPF) full stack, I'd like to see how they differ...

Comment: @Rado any luck with this?